# Cannot assign string with single quote in golang

Tags: string, go

I am learning go and when playing with string I noticed that if a string is in single quotes then golang is giving me an error but double quotes are working fine.

```
func main() {
    var a string
    a = 'hello' //will give error
    a = "hello" //will not give error
}
```

This is the error I get on my system:

```
illegal rune literal
```

While when I try to do the same on playground I am getting this error:

```
prog.go:9: missing '
prog.go:9: syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }
prog.go:9: newline in string
prog.go:9: empty character literal or unescaped ' in character literal
prog.go:9: missing '
```

I am not able to understand the exact reason behind this as in for example Python, Perl one can declare a string with both single and double quote.

Comment: Other languages treat any non-whitespace as comment and all keywords are made of spaces, tabs and newlines. "Other languages" is _never_ a good argument, not for programming languages and not for natural languages.

Comment: "newline in rune literal" my mistake was accidentally using a single quote instead of a backtick.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In Go, `'⌘'` represents a single character (called a Rune), whereas `"⌘"` represents a string containing the character `⌘`.

This is true in many programming languages where the difference between strings and characters is notable, such as C++.

Check out the "Code points, characters, and runes" section in the [Go Blog on Strings](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

Comment: You can also use `\`blah\`` back ticks for a raw string.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, if you are wanting to embed double quotes:

```
package main

func main() {
   s := `west "north" east`
   println(s)
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#raw_string_lit

Answer (score 1):

Go is a statically typed language. Also Go is not a scripting language. Though we see Go is running like a scripting language, it is compiling the source we write and then execute the main function. So, we should treat Go as C, Java, C++ where single quote `'` is used to declare characters (`rune, char`) unlike scripting languages like Python or JavaScript.

I think as this is a new language, and current trend is lying with scripting languages,  this confusion has been occurred.

Comment: This explanation is a bit confusing. It's not true that _all_ 'scripting languages' (by which I understand you mean _interpreted_ languages, as opposed to compiled ones...) do not distinguish between `'` and `"`, or that, just because they are 'scripted', they do not distinguish between _characters_ and _strings_. This is true  in the cases which you've mentioned, but it's just a coincidence — one that applies to the most known & used languages. But it's not a _universal rule_, by all means.

Comment: Also, what you call a 'scripted' language _can_ be compiled (there are JS compilers, Lua compilers...) and not merely _interpreted_; and 'scripted' languages _can_ be strongly-typed as well (e.g. TypeScript, or the little-used Linden Scripting Language used in the virtual world platforms Second Life and OpenSimulator).
Last but not least, Go is _not_ really a 'new language'; it's been around since 2007. Ruby on Rails was released around 2005; Rust possibly in 2006. Sure, they are all programming languages from the 21st century, while Java, C#, Python, JavaScript, Lua, come from the 1990s.

Comment: ... in that sense, Go is 'newer' than the heavyweights. C++ is slightly older, from the mid-1980s; and, of course, C, which has been launched together with Unix, dates from the late 1960s/early 1970s. There are, however, much older languages (consider the cases of Fortran, COBOL, Lisp, then Algol, Pascal...), some of which are still used (Lisp is a particularly good example!).
My point is that 'new' or 'old', in this context, is of little relevance to the OP's issue. Explaining the syntax difference between a `rune` and a `string` is!

Answer (score 0):

**Double, Single and Back quotes**

**Double and back quotes can be used to define a string.**

Single quotes will not allow to put more than one characters.
If a string with escape characters is formatted in double quotes, escape characters can be interpreted.
If a string with escape characters is formatted in back quotes, escape characters are ignored.

**Single quotes**
A character is formatted in single quotes can either be a byte or a rune.
If we don’t declare the type, the default type will be rune.