# GCP list instances and filter by last start timestamp

Tags: go, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to list instances with a `lastStartTimestamp` less than a given date.

```golang
import (
    compute "cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    _ "google.golang.org/api/option"
    protobuf "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
)

func List(ctx context.Context, project string) error {

    filter := "lastStartTimestamp < '2021-09-10T00:00:00.000-07:00'"

    req := &protobuf.AggregatedListInstancesRequest{
        Project: project,
        Filter:  &filter,
    }

    it := c.client.AggregatedList(ctx, req)

    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        for _, instance := range resp.Value.Instances {
            fmt.Println(instance.GetName(), instance.GetLastStartTimestamp())
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

However it's throwing an error

```
Error 400: Invalid value for field 'filter': 'lastStartTimestamp < '2021-09-10T00:00:00.000-07:00''.
```

Is this possible and am I going about it the right way? Or do I need to analyse the `lastStartTimestamp` post query?

---

What I've tried

```
filter := `lastStartTimestamp < "2021-09-18T20:44:14.151-07:00"`
```

Comment: The examples use double-quoted strings, but the timestamp in your code uses single quotes. Have you tried using double quotes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691045/cannot-assign-string-with-single-quote-in-golang/34691123

Comment: Thanks all, coming from Python so was unsure of the syntax. John link guided me on what to do, and then I used double quotes around the date.

Comment: @DietrichEpp did you have a link to the examples? I thought I fixed it but apparently not. Back ticks with double quotes hasn't worked.

Comment: The examples are here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list

Comment: Thanks, then I'm guessing the comparison is not supported. I can do `=`, but not `>` or `<`, I'm assuming `gcloud` must support this through some sort of post processing .

Answer (score 1):

To recap the comments:
Currently only 'equal' comparison is supported, you cannot filter instances started after or before certain timestamp. As a workaround I would suggest pulling a complete list, sorted by `creationTimestamp desc`, and then filtering instances in the code.

Timestamp must be in double quotation marks:

```
lastStartTimestamp="2021-09-09T04:48:04.761-07:00"
```

API can be tested [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list). Information on quotation in go, including escape characters, can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-print-string-with-double-quotes-in-golang/).